# Can be used class row inside Bootstrap to set image width 100%?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can be used class row inside Bootstrap to set image width 100%?
Example:

```
<div class="row"> and not
.image100 {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No. `row` is a predefined grid class. It is used for placing columns inside it. What you want to do is treat an `<img>` tag as a `span12` or `col-md-12` class. It does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does this automatically for you. Try:

> `<div class="row">
>      <div class="col-md-12">
>         <img src="bigImage.ext">
>      </div>
>   </div>`

All you need to do is provide a big enough image and Bootstrap should automatically spread it completely to cover the row.